# Push сообщения в Android, используя GCM, работают для одного ProductID но не работают для другого

Tags: android

Есть две Google Developer Console, в каждой есть проект, с подключенным API Google Cloud Messaging и есть одно приложение. Для одного проекта, используя его productID (Sender ID) и сгенерированный API Key приходит один токен и пуш сообщения отлично работают с ним, для другого проекта, используя его Server API и productID приходит соответственно другой токен, но при попытке его использовать сервер всегда возвращает "error":"NotRegistered". В чем может быть причина?